# How to appendchild only one time in form validation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add appendchild only once when I click submit, but it shows many times.

```
if(input_name.value =="" ||input_email.value =="" || input_password.value =="")
{
    var tag = document.createElement("p");
    var text = document.createTextNode("all input are reqired");
    tag.appendChild(text);
    var element = document.getElementById("new");
    element.appendChild(tag);
}
```

Comment: So you click the submit button once and you get many `all input are reqired`  messages?

Comment: no when condition true it show one time but when I click agin  it show agin I want to make it one time only when Iclick not many time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a new element every time, have the element in the html but empty then when you have an error put the message in.

```
<div id='new'><p></p></div>
```

```
var element = document.querySelector("#new p");
if(input_name.value =="" ||input_email.value =="" || input_password.value =="")
{
    element.innerHTML = 'all input are reqired';
}
else{
    element.innerHTML = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, do you want this.

```
if(input_name.value =="" ||input_email.value =="" || input_password.value =="")
{
    if(document.getElementById("validationmessage"))return;
    var tag = document.createElement("p");
    tag.id="validationmessage";
    var text = document.createTextNode("all input are reqired");
    tag.appendChild(text);
    var element = document.getElementById("new");
    element.appendChild(tag);
}
```

And you need remove the "validationmessage" when it valid.

```
    if(input_name.value !="" &&input_email.value !="" && input_password.value !="")
    {
        var tag = document.getElementById("validationmessage");
        if(!tag)return;
        var element = document.getElementById("new");
        element.removeChild(tag);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validate(){
  const validationError = document.getElementById("requiredMsg");
  const pass = document.getElementById("pass");
  const name = document.getElementById("name");
  const email = document.getElementById("email");
  if(name.value=="" || email.value=="" || pass.value==""){
    validationError.classList.replace("hide", "show");
    return;
  }else{
    validationError.classList.replace("show", "hide");
  }
  
}
```

```css
.show{
display:block
}

.hide{
display:none
}
```

```html
<p class="hide" id="requiredMsg">All Inputs are required.</p>

Name  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
Pass  <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass">
Email  <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
<button onClick="validate()">Validate</button>
```